# Finding distance from valid number

Tags: python, math

I have a game related problem that is pretty complex. Here is the simplified version of the problem. I have a list of "good" numbers.

```
100
101
102
104
105
106
107
220
221
289
290
```

The customer has a choice of 3 numbers 103, 299 and 999

103 is the best choice because it is closest to the good numbers. 299 is better option than 999 because of the distance from good numbers.

I guess python does not has any built-in function to calculate the "distance". But python has surprised me before.

I need to find the distance of each value. for e.g.

```
103 0.9
299 0.2
999 0.1
```

I tried machine learning from Amazon but it returns the same weight for all numbers.

---

Update:

```
mylist="""100
101
102
104
105
106
107
220
221
289
290
542
544
"""

z = """103
299
999
108
543
"""

finallist=[]

for y in z.split():
    newlist=[]
    for i in mylist.split():
        diff=int(y)-int(i)
        newlist.append(abs(diff))
    finallist.append((y, min(newlist)))

finallist
[('103', 1), ('299', 9), ('999', 455), ('108', 1), ('543', 1)]
```

1) 103 and 108 are at par. But 103 is more relevant because it is between 102 and 104, I want to increase the weight of 103

2)  103 is also part of contiguous series and therefore more important than 543 that may be in between 542 and 544

3) amazon ML does all this calculation and provide the "score". But that did not work in this case.

---

Update 2:

removed the min function and saved all values into list

```
#    finallist.append((y, newlist))
```

counted the number of occurrences for each value.

```
from collections import Counter

for i, d in finallist:
    c=Counter(d)
    print i, c.most_common()

103 [(1, 2), (2, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (117, 1), (118, 1), (439, 1), (441, 1), (186, 1), (187, 1)]
299 [(192, 1), (193, 1), (194, 1), (195, 1), (197, 1), (198, 1), (199, 1), (9, 1), (10, 1), (78, 1), (79, 1), (243, 1), (245, 1)]
999 [(897, 1), (898, 1), (899, 1), (709, 1), (710, 1), (455, 1), (457, 1), (778, 1), (779, 1), (892, 1), (893, 1), (894, 1), (895, 1)]
108 [(1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (4, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 1), (112, 1), (113, 1), (434, 1), (436, 1), (181, 1), (182, 1)]
543 [(1, 2), (322, 1), (323, 1), (436, 1), (437, 1), (438, 1), (439, 1), (441, 1), (442, 1), (443, 1), (253, 1), (254, 1)]
```

103 is more relevant because it has 2 occurrences of 1,2 and 3 as compared to 108 and 543

I an trying to sort in this order:

```
103 because it has highest number of double occurances
108 because it is part of contiguous list
543 because of the instance of double occurance
299 because closer to list
999 least relevant
```

If that is not possible, it is ok if I get 103, 543, 108 ...

---

Update 3:

I tried the average instead of minimum as suggested in the answer.

```
# finallist.append((y, sum(newlist)/len(mylist)))
```

Now the order is 108, 103, 299, 543 and 999 which is not expected. And this may change if very large number is added to the list.

```
[('103', 28.923076923076923),
 ('299', 39.07692307692308),
 ('999', 195.30769230769232),
 ('108', 28.634615384615383),
 ('543', 81.34615384615384)]
```

---

final update:

I will simply calculate total and then sort. This does not return expected results, but I will accept this answer because I do not know how to assign "weight" to each value based on distance.

```
finallist.append((y, sum(newlist)))
```

sorted(finallist, key=lambda x: x[1])

[('108', 1489), ('103', 1504), ('299', 2032), ('543', 4230), ('999', 10156)]

Comment: how do you define the distance?

Comment: So, a larger "distance" is "closer"?

Comment: Yes. larger distance is closer. But it is not hard and fast rule. All I need to do is to sort and take first or last number.

Comment: Just find the `min` of the differences from your number to any of the numbers in the list? Or do you need some faster approach than that? Or does the value have to be between 0 and 1? Right now, your question is pretty unclear.

Comment: Maybe you could calculate your distance as `sum(1/(abs(x-y)+1) for y in list)` or something similar?

Comment: But that does not consider the relevance as mentioned in the point (2) of the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual distance from one point to another on the real line, is the absolute value of the difference.

```
abs( a - b )
```

So an iterator (python3) over the distance is : `map( lambda x: abs(x-a), l )`
From there, you can compute the average the distance

```
average_distance = sum( map( lambda x: abs(x-a), good_numbers ) ) / len( good_numbers )
```

The point with the best age distance to good numbers is the point that tends to be closest to good numbers.  The average, unlike the minimum, may not give you a point closest to a good number, but overall, closest to them all.

Answer (score 1):

Make some kind of data **clusterization**. I think that k-Means or another algorithm should be included in python math/scipy libraries.

Find **centroid** and weight of every cluster (for (542,544) centroid is 543, mass is 2).

Choose needed **metrics** for your "score" - it could be simple inverse distance to the closest centroid, weighted distance (accounting cluster size `Weight/R`), gravitation power `Weight/R^2` and so on.